# Have trouble making a phase line plot with Maple.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

> Draw the phase line, and sketch several graphs of solutions in the $ty$-plane

Is the directions for my homework.

I have tried the Phase Portraits for Autonomous Systems under tasks, but I don't have two functions.

Only have simple one variable differential equations functions: $\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2-3$

Could someone gives me a minimum working example.

Comment: Please solve this equation first by separation of variables. -- For the given functionality, you can use $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$ as first component.

Comment: @LutzL did not think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a differential equation for the time via the initial value problem $\frac{dx}{dt}=1$, $x(t_0)=t_0$, so that $x(t)=t$ at all times.

Comment: could you point me to a reference that explains this, because I am just now learning about differential equations.

Comment: This is the standard method to turn a non-autonomous system into an autonomous system. Should be in every textbook where these terms are introduced.